# Weird Json in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am learning the ELK Stack for log analysis and one thing I can't digest is whenever we have to populate index, the JSON format we have to use is not really a JSON.
For Eg:
Following is from tutorialspoint website, to populate a "Schools" index with 
"School" type for bulk population :-

```
{ "index":{ "_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"1" }}
{"name":"Central School", "description":"CBSE Affiliation", "street":"Nagan","city":"paprola", "state":"HP", "zip":"176115", "location"[31.8955385, 76.8380405],"fees":2000, "tags":["Senior Secondary", "beautiful campus"], "rating":"3.5"}
{ "index":{ "_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"2" }}
{ "name":"Saint Paul School", "description":"ICSE Afiliation", "street":"Dawarka", "city":"Delhi", "state":"Delhi", "zip":"110075","location":[28.5733056, 77.0122136], "fees":5000,"tags":["Good Faculty", "Great Sports"], "rating":"4.5"}
```

Now I do understand space is the delimiter here and without giving one entity (*index info or school info*) in one line,it will return with parsing error. But according to my understanding and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_json_syntax.asp) (for reference), I think we do need a top level **Key**(*Schools in below*) with array (**[ ]**) of set of data(*index info and School info*) in above maybe like below :

```
{"Schools" : [
  {
    {"index":{ "_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"1" }},
    {"name":"Central School", "description":"CBSE Affiliation", "street":"Nagan","city":"paprola", "state":"HP", "zip":"176115", "location"[31.8955385, 76.8380405],"fees":2000, "tags":["Senior Secondary", "beautiful campus"], "rating":"3.5"}
  },
  {
    { "index":{ "_index":"schools", "_type":"school", "_id":"2" }},
    { "name":"Saint Paul School", "description":"ICSE Afiliation", "street":"Dawarka", "city":"Delhi", "state":"Delhi", "zip":"110075","location":[28.5733056, 77.0122136], "fees":5000,"tags":["Good Faculty", "Great Sports"], "rating":"4.5"}
  }
]}
```

I also tried changing the type of payload in POSTMAN from *JSON(applicaton/json)* to *TEXT* but it gives back an error stating that former payload is required.

I am clearly missing something here. It will be very helpful if someone can reason above behaviour.

Comment: if you mention index and type in the elasticsearch  endpoint url you can skip that part  for ex: `localhost:port/schools/school/1`

Comment: and if you are new to elasticsearch , use it with kibana it will be more helpful than the curl or terminal based method .

Comment: Yes Ankur, I am continuing my learning by trying integrations with Kibana and Logstash. But, still I want to know why they don't use a Universal/Well Known format.

Comment: Hi @AnkitChauhan I can't understand what is your question. For bulk batch operation Elasticsearch uses a not regular json format. In what kind of operation this creates problem for you?

Comment: Hi @Lupanoide I just want to know why they are using **"not regular json format"**. Is there any story/reason behind that? or was this adopted in later versions of elasticsearch?

Comment: It allways been like that. It is thought to be used in a json file, giving the possibility to dump an index. Then you use this file, invoking his path in a curl call, example: $ curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST localhost:9200/name_of_index/_bulk --data-binary "@path/of/your/data.json"; echo. More reference here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html or here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_batch_processing.html

Comment: indeed if you want to costruct bulk request in python bulk java you could use helpers.

Comment: Ok Thank You @Lupanoide. Your 2nd last comment helps.